# How to validate image from external source

Tags: php, laravel

User can paste image url on form, then my app download this on local server. I would like validate this image, but i have problem.

Input:

```
$image = "http://example.com/image.png";
```

Rules, but not working

```
'image' => [
   'required', 
   'url', 
   'mimes:jpeg,png', 
   'max:5120', 
   'dimensions:min_width=400,min_height=400', 
   new FileExtensionRule(['png', 'jpg', 'jpeg'])
]
```

How can I validate image from external source.

Comment: Can you expand on "Not working" please?

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I have message The :attribute failed to upload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to make custom rule [Custom Validation Rules](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation#custom-validation-rules)

```
php artisan make:rule RemoteImage
```

and then put your logic inside this function in the RemoteImage class

```
public function passes($attribute, $value)
{
    return strtoupper($value) === $value;
}
```

to get file type

```
$image = "http://example.com/image.png";
$ext = pathinfo($image, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

to get the file size to validate

using curl

```
 $ch = curl_init('http://example.com/image.png');

 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, TRUE);

 $data = curl_exec($ch);
 $size = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_LENGTH_DOWNLOAD);

 curl_close($ch);
 echo $size;
```

Comment: How can I check image pixel size?

Comment: It is easy

    list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize("http://example.com/image.png");
    echo $width;
    echo $height;